# Does the 'Supporting Files' folder increase launch time/CPU consumption?

Tags: ios, uiimage

If I have a lot of images/etc in the Supporting Files folder does that increase CPU consumption and slow the launch time of the app? Does the app have to load all these files on launch.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

No. In general these are copied into the apps bundle at compile time, letting the app access them when it needs them (by finding the files).